# add ArrayList to multiple ArrayList in java

Tags: java

Hi i have problem with ArrayLists i have 3 lists

```
ArrayList1<Integer>=[1,2,3]
ArrayList2<Integer>=[]
ArrayList3<ArrayList<Integer>>=[]
```

ArrayList1 elements are used for adding values to ArrayList2
for example

```
for(int i:ArrayList1)
{
  for(int a=0;a<i;a++)
  {
    ArrayList2.add(a);
  }

}
```

and that works fine no problem there but now i want to for every element in ArrayList1 to add ArrayList2 to ArrayList3 this is what I have come up with but it does not work

```
 for(int i:ArrayList1)
    {
      for(int a=0;a<i;a++)
      {
        ArrayList2.add(a);
      }
      ArrayList3.add(ArrayList2);
    }
```

Comment: this does not look like syntaxically-valid java ...

Comment: `for(int i:ArrayList1)` should be `for(Integer i:ArrayList1)`

Comment: @Zhuinden `for (int i : arrayList1)` compiles and runs fine, thanks to auto-unboxing. Unless there is a null in there ^^

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `addAll`, and `Collections.fill`.

**Example**

```
list2.addAll(list1);
list3 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(list1.size());
Collections.fill(list3, list2);
```

Note that `list3` will be filled with the **same** instance of `list2`.

This means that every change to `list2` will be reflected in each element of `list3`.

If this is not the behavior you're expecting, iterate over the length of `list1` and add a `new ArrayList<Integer>(list2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int a=0;a<i;a++)
```

is wrong. You must not stop at `a < i`, it makes no sense! You want to add the whole arrayList2 to ArrayList3, not a number of integers equal to the value of the int i in ArrayList1.

Comment: if the n-th element of array1 is 3, you just add to arraylist3 3 elements of arraylist2, it makes no sense.

Comment: don't hold *the grudge* (bad music pun here).